# curl PUT using auth token header to mesosphere fails without eval

Tags: bash, http, curl, mesosphere, quoting

> EDIT:

I have managed to make it work with

```
response=$(
  curl -k -X PUT -d "$marathon_payload" --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output "$tmp"\
       -H "Authorization: token=$dcos_token" -H "$header_content_type"  $app_id_url
)
```

The single quotes were causing the problem. It took a few gyrations but all good.

MORAL: quotes inside the value don't matter if the value is properly quoted UNLESS you eval the whole thing, and I should have known that. Occam's wins again.

> end edit

I am initiating Mesosphere microservice deployments with `curl`, but it won't succeed without using `eval`. Since I recently inherited this code I've been trying to scrub the `eval` out of it just as a matter of habit, but it's thwarting me.

The script initiates the deployment with

```
response=$(
 eval curl -k -X PUT -d "'$marathon_payload'" --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output $tmp\
       -H "'Authorization: token=$dcos_token'" -H "'$header_content_type'" $app_id_url
)
```

If it gets a 200 or a 201, it loops a `curl` to effectively screen-scrape the deployments page till the request disappears.

```
chkDeploy() { rm -f $tmp;
  eval curl -k -X GET --silent --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output $tmp\
            -H "'Authorization: token=$dcos_token'" -H "'$header_content_type'" $deployments_url
}
response=$( chkDeploy )
```

`$dcos_token` is a base64 encoded string.

It then checks the service with another `curl` loop to the info page so it can verify the version number. ***This one is working fine with no eval.***

```
chkCode() {
  curl -k -X GET --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output $tmp $info_url;
}
response=$( chkCode )
```

The first two return 401, authentication failure. 
I'm guessing the auth token quoting is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use `eval` here; you just need to quote the arguments to `-H` properly.

```
response=$(
  curl -k -X PUT -d "$marathon_payload" \
     --write-out %{http_code} \
     --silent --output "$tmp" \
     -H "Authorization: token=$dcos_token" \
     -H "$header_content_type" "$app_id_url"
)
```

Comment: `$marathon_payload` is *loaded* with quotes, so there's an embedded pair of single-quotes to isolate them from the ones around the value as a whole. Same for several of those. Without those it's a 400 (Bad Request),

Comment: I was going to point out that I removed those quotes, and forgot. What is the value of `marathon_payload`? It's probably cleaner to include those quotes *in* the value rather than expecting the caller to know that additional data needs to be included the argument to `-d`.

Comment: It's several dozen lines of JSON with doublequotes around all the keys and the values, as maintained by a different team on a dedicated git repo. I have limited control of that... but I wrapped an echo around it and it's working - 

`response=$( curl -k -X PUT -d "$( echo "$marathon_payload" )" --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output "$tmp" -H "Authorization: token=$dcos_token" -H "$header_content_type" $app_id_url )`

Apparently it was the payload. :)

Comment: I knew it *shouldn't* need an eval and it was driving me crazy, lol

Comment: OK, in that case you *definitely* don't need the single quotes. If `curl -d '{"name": "value"}' ...` works, then so does `d='{"name": "value"}'; curl -d "$d" ...`.